# Trouble understanding how Devise Strategies work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, warden

In the Rails app I am working on, there is a need for a custom devise strategy that will sign in an admin as another user and allow for that admin to easily log back in.

I have searched through google results but nothing really shows you have to use a custom strategy.

Here is my strategy: (config/sign_in_as.rb)

```
require 'devise/strategies/authenticatable'

module Devise
  module Strategies
    class SignInAs < Authenticatable

      def valid?
        user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
        user && has_contributor_access? && current_user.can_manage?(user)
      end

      def authenticate!
        resource = User.find_by_id params[:id]

        if resource
          success!(resource)
        else
          fail!("Error")
        end
      end

      private
        def has_contributor_access?
          current_user.school_admin? || current_user.athlete_contributor?
        end
    end
  end
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:sign_in_as, Devise::Strategies::SignInAs)
```

SignInAsController:

```
class SignInAsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    sign_out(current_user)
    # How to incorporate custom strategy?
    sign_in(:user)
    redirect_to user_root_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this gem user_impersonate [here](https://github.com/engineyard/user_impersonate). Its using the same strategies that you want.